# Eclipse Formatting breaks EL expressions inside JavaScript script

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp, formatting, el

Wow, the title is quite a mouth full. Let me explain. I have a `.jsp` page, on this page is a JavaScript `<script ..>` element and inside the JavaScript there is an EL expression (`${..}`). The code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var HOST_ID = ${host.id};
    ...
  });
</script>
```

**The Problem:**
The Eclipse JavaScript formatter will per default expand `${host.id}` over multiple lines. I am guessing that the EL expression is somehow interpreted as a JavaScript object. Anyway, the tag will make end up looking like this:

```
var HOST_ID = $
{
  host.id
}
;
```

**=> This actually breaks the code!**

If split over multiple lines the tag is no longer recognized as valid EL expression and execution of the JavaScript code will stop throwing around exceptions.

I know about a way to turn off formatting adhoc in the Java formatter using tags (`// @formatter:off` or `on`) but there is no such option for the JavaScript formatter in Eclipse.

---

The only way to fix (read workaround) this is to force the JavaScript formatter to *never* expand objects. But this is problematic in two ways:

- Not expanding objects can be very messy and lead to extremely unreadable code.
- Expanding objects over multiple lines is a *default* in the Eclipse JavaScript formatter.

This means if any member of my team accidentially auto-formats a `.jsp` file containing the described construct the code will silently break. It still looks like valid JS, and passes build etc, but at execution time it won't work.

---

Does anyone have any solution for this? The best solution would be to somehow disable formatting with a tag like the one used in the Java formatter (this solution works without enforcing company/teamwide formatter standards or hoping no one will accidentally hit Shift+Ctrl+F).

Comment: That's not JSTL. That's EL. JavaScript is also not a scriptlet. I fixed the wrong terminology. To learn what JSTL really is, read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info To learn what a scriptlet really is, read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scriptlet/info

Comment: Thanks. I got massively confused by all the different tags while using JSP/Java/Struts2/JavaScript in one environment... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is possible to wrap EL expressions in *single quotes*. This will make them look like a string in JavaScript, but they will still be evaluated as EL expressions.

So changing

```
var HOST_ID = ${host.id};
```

to

```
var HOST_ID = '${host.id}';
```

actually does the trick. The Eclipse JavaScript formatter now thinks of the expression as a string and does not expand it. Problem solved.

Comment: This is not a complete solution as the output of the EL tags is not always a  String. When you have a JSON string as the output of the EL tag and you want to read the JSON String as a Javascript object, enclosing them in single quotes will mess your functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution at the time I am writing this suggests wrapping the EL expression in single quotes as a solution to the problem.  If you decide to do this and the value in the EL expression is a boolean, be very careful as the value is now a string in Javascript and conditional comparisons might not work as expected...

Assume that you have a boolean variable host.isActive and the value is true.

```
var HOST_IS_ACTIVE1 = ${host.isActive}; // var type is boolean in Javascript

if (HOST_IS_ACTIVE1 == true) {
  // this code will be executed
}

if (HOST_IS_ACTIVE1 == 'true') {
  // this code will not be executed
}

var HOST_IS_ACTIVE2 = '${host.isActive}'; // var type is string in Javascript

if (HOST_IS_ACTIVE2 == true) {
  // this code will NOT be executed
}

if (HOST_IS_ACTIVE2 == 'true') {
  // this code will be executed
}
```